# Volume Using Integration

Tags: integration

"Let $B$ be the solid whose base is the circle $x^2+y^2 =1^2$ and whose vertical cross
sections perpendicular to the $x$-axis are equilateral triangles. Compute the volume of $B$."

Any suggestions? I thought I had set up my integral correctly.

Comment: Can you share your integral with us? Notice that when you rearrange $x^2+y^2=12$ into $y = \sqrt{12 - x^2}$, this only gives the top half of the circle. To find how long the triangle's bases are, you need to multiply that by $2$.

Comment: Would the integral not be [-1,1]? First off I made a mistake its 1^2 not 12. But because 1 is radius would that not be the integral?

Comment: It would also help to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The same principle still applies, whether the radius is $1$ or $12$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The width of the circle at some $x$ value is given by
$$2\sqrt{1-x^2}$$
and so, since the area of the equilateral triangle with side length $l$ is given by
$$\frac{\sqrt 3}{4}l^2$$
we have that the volume of the solid is
$$V=\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\sqrt 3}{4}\big(2\sqrt{1-x^2}\big)^2dx$$
or
$$V=\int_{-1}^{1}\sqrt 3 (1-x^2) dx$$
Can you evaluate this?

Comment: Yes, thank you! Just made a simple arithmetic error.

Comment: @Frpzzd Your last step still has the bounds as $-\sqrt{12}$ and $\sqrt{12}$.

Comment: @NeilH No problem! If this helped, don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark}$!

Comment: @TobyMak Thanks, fixed!